# Custom URL's and deep linking

Tags: deep-linking, custom-url, ios-universal-links

As universal links require iOS 9 and are not compatible with iOS 8, is it possible to cater for custom URL's and universal links in the same app so that if an app is installed on an iPhone running iOS 8 and on an iPhone running iOS 9 the URL scheme will forward the user to the app? If not are there any other solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

## YES

---

I created a demo app called Universal Links with Development target support of iOS8+ (https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/iOS-Universal-Links). In which I support both URI Scheme for iOS8+ and Universal Links for iOS9.2+.

You can download the source code from github and test it yourself. Here the website link which support

**Main Page** - https://vineetchoudhary.github.io/iOS-Universal-Links/
**Home Page** - https://vineetchoudhary.github.io/iOS-Universal-Links/home
**About Page** - https://vineetchoudhary.github.io/iOS-Universal-Links/about

[image]

---

and URI Scheme for is `universallinks://`
[image]

---

Screenshot of iOS 9.2 and iOS 8.4

[image]
[image]

Hope this is helpful to you!